# how can I edit in page number of pdf file within a shadow DOM through selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, pdf, shadow-dom

Actually I have local pdf file and I want to open it in chrome browser and edit the page number in viewed pdf. I already opened it in browser but I can't find the element.

This is my chromeDriverCode.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file://"+excelFileRow.getPathFile());
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

this all what is the output

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="file:///home/shibo/Downloads/project2.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="4" /></body></html>
```

This picture show what I see in inspect.

[image]

How can I update page number .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _edit the page number_ or _update page number_ ? What is your exact manual step?

Comment: selenium code will open pdf in chrome browser .it is okay but i want to edit in page number field . if i have a pdf file from 500 page .when it is opened  by default it will start from 1 i want to get page number 50 as example

Comment: As you can observe the _Page number_ label and it's associated tags are within shadow dom, you have to use _JavascriptExecutor_ . Can you expand the nodes in between for a proper analysis?